# How to access specific data in a JSON response in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, jsonresponse

Here is my code I am getting response and I want to use some values in that
I wrote like this but error is coming

```
let id = json["emp_id"] as! [String:Any]
let parameters = [
        "email": empEm,
        "password":"1234"
        ] as [String : Any]
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/company/employee/login") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
    request.httpBody = httpBody


    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
                let id = json["emp_id"] as! [String:Any]


            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }

        }.resume()
```

my response is

```
{
    available = 3;
    compoff = 0;
    displayname = Vamsi;
    "emp_id" = 001;
    gender = Male;
    id = 1;
    leaves = 4;
    rating = 0;
    star = 0;
    "termination_date" = active;
    wfh = 0;
}
```

I want to take details like id, emp_id from the response

Comment: What "error is coming"? Show us the error. Also, the response you posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: Type 'Any' has no subscript members in this line.                    let id = json["emp_id"] as! [String:Any]

Comment: This has been asked 100000 times. You have to cast the result: `let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String:Any]` And the value of `emp_id` is string. `let id = json["emp_id"] as! String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decode your JSON like this:

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
```

The return value of `JSONSerialization.jsonObject` is `Any`, so you need to tell the compiler specifically what kind of object the JSON represents. In your case it is a dictionary, so use `[String: Any]`